# "Graph Editor" animation handles missing?

Tags: animation, keyframes, graph-editor

This is a very very very simple question and probably simply a mistake on my part but I'm asking on the part of all other people who (like me) aren't the best at animation.
I have a very simple scene of a cylinder flying along the "Y" axis and I want to be able to get the animation curve handles in the "Graph Editor" except, there are none. **What do I need to do to get handles to adjust the animation within the graph editor?**
*Pic below of how my Graph Editor looks*
[image]

Comment: maybe scroll down?

Comment: ... or up :) Or press Numpad "." (Frame Selected)

Comment: I won with the scroll down  ^^

Comment: @moonboots Yup! I would've marked your question as the answer except you didn't write the format as an actual answer, but rather just posted a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to scroll down. I initially tried that, I apparently just didn't scroll down enough.